# Debug an Outlook web add-in on Outlook 2013 and 2016

Tags: debugging, outlook, ms-office, outlook-web-addins

I would like to know how to efficiently debug a webb add-in (manifest.xml) add-in, and how to test it in anterior/past versions of Outlook (2013-2016).

More details : our team is struggling at debugging an outlook web add-in. It is published on the MS store.

Some of our customers are complaining about a weird behaviour (same for all), and I know they're using Outlook 2013 and 2016. Thing is, we can only test our add-in on our Office 365 developer E5 license and there, it works perfectly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can see if this link helps you install the 2013 and 2016 clients.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Hi, this does not help unfortunately. Please tell me that you, the Outlook Add-ins Team has more help to provide than this link ?

Comment: Are you unable to install Outlook 2013/2016 clients, or are you looking for debugging instructions after installing these older clients?